# How to count words in doc,xls,pdf and txt file

Tags: php, html

I have a scenario in which I need to count the number of words in file.
I have different file formats such as `.doc`, `.xls`, `.pdf` and `.txt`. I am using this method for counting:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="docfile" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $file = $_FILES['docfile']['name'];
        $file = str_replace(" ","_",$file);
        //$file = file_get_contents($file);

        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['docfile']['tmp_name'],"uploads/".$file);

        if($ext == "txt" || $ext == "pdf" || $ext == "doc" || $ext == "docx"){
            $file = file_get_contents("uploads/".$file);
            echo str_word_count($file);
        }
    }
?>
```

But it is not returning the correct word count for the file.

Comment: What's it returning? Use `str_word_count($file,0)`

Comment: it is returning the count.

Comment: I am so confused... It is not returning the count? But it is returning the count?

Comment: it is returning count but the same count, your code did not change any thing. the count is wrong

Comment: It is returning the count but not perfect count..

Comment: Does this work for .txt files? PHP isn't natively aware of how doc, xls, pdf etc. are formatted, so you won't get the correct counts for those. You'll need to find libraries which can handle them, or make your own (quite difficult). txt should be fine, though.

Comment: No, It is not giving the exact number of counts of .txt file too.

Comment: [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/), [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), but PDF is so much of a moving target that it's pretty much impossible. There is no guarantee that "words" will be represented in a continuous block in the PDF structure, there's not even a guarantee they will be represented as text. People do some unbelievably stupid things when generating PDF files.

Answer (score 4):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) is a Java framework that is capable of recognizing a lot of document types and extracting meta information from them.  It is is capable of ascertaining word counts for a lot of the document types it recognizes.

I mention this Java framework for your PHP question because there is a PHP wrapper for it called [PhpTikaWrapper](https://github.com/pierroweb/PhpTikaWrapper).  I have never used the wrapper but Apache Tika can extract the meta information you are after so, investigating the wrapper may prove beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a difficult task there. `.doc` `.pdf` and `.xls` are not simply readable. To test this try opening a pdf with a basic text editor like `notepad` or `gedit`. You will see what appears to be gibberish. This is the same thing PHP sees when you read a file's contents.

`.xls` and `.doc` can probably be parsed with PHPWord and PHPExcel from [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice). You will need to look in to these libraries. I don't know anything for PDFs but there's probably something.

I would suggest writing a series of classes that all implement a similar interface so you can switch them out depending on the extension.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Php understands text, but cannot understand content of pdf, doc, xls and other non-text-based file formats. Php function you've used does only work with simple text.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a general purpose class that incorporates various methods found around the web and on Stack Overflow that provides word, line and page counts for doc, docx, pdf and txt files. I hope it's of use to people. If anyone can get RTF working with it I'd love a pull request! https://github.com/joeblurton/doccounter

Comment: have you tried this package? I tried this and its not working properly. Its not working for PDF at all.

Comment: I was hoping this would be more robust but I abandoned it in favour of an AWS approach. I couldn't find any solution that would work on shared hosting without reverse engineering the formats, so used a mixture of a headless Libre Office install on Ubuntu and the pdftotext cli program (I think this comes with Poppler) to handle conversion of all documents, and then just used the output of the Unix wc program to get lines and words. Convert all docs to PDF and you can count the pages, although I had to install lots of proprietary fonts in order to avoid reflow issues. It was a pain. And slow.